# ReactJS MUI v5 Autocomplete create option always visible

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

As in documentation MUI Autocomplete is able to create an option using `freeSolo` prop. New option appears at the bottom only when the user start typing. Is it possible to move that option at top and make it always visible? I may reorder it with flexbox, so this should not be a problem that much if it can not do it automatically. The problem is the visibility of that option.
I want to open a drawer when it is clicked, so I do not need that typed text information.

That option `Add "something"` should be always visible, how is it possible?